# How to show user travelling path with user current location. in v.10

Tags: android, mapbox

Unable to find the solution to show user traveled path with current location on Mapbox.
i have tried with **LocationObserver** onNewLocationMatcherResult we recived location.
but when user is left phone on ideal that will provide different location most of the time(without user moment)

Mapbox v10

```
private val locationObserver = object : LocationObserver {
    override fun onNewRawLocation(rawLocation: Location) {

    }

    override fun onNewLocationMatcherResult(locationMatcherResult: LocationMatcherResult) {
        Log.i(
            "onNewLocationMatcherResult: ",
            "${locationMatcherResult.enhancedLocation.toJson()}"
        )
        val enhancedLocation = locationMatcherResult.enhancedLocation
        navigationLocationProvider.changePosition(
            enhancedLocation,
            locationMatcherResult.keyPoints,
        )

       // add or drawPolyLine in both case when user select sports type or challemge
        viewModel.addCoordinates(enhancedLocation)
        updateCamera(
            enhancedLocation.latitude,
            enhancedLocation.longitude,
            enhancedLocation.bearing.toDouble()
        )
        viewModel.setLocationData(enhancedLocation)
        drawPolyLine()
    }
}
```

`onNewLocationMatcherResult` I received differ location most of time.